# std::string change size but doesn't content

Tags: c++, stdstring

```
mt19937 rn;
std::string paillier = c.handle_response(req,msgreceive, concessionaria); //receive string from socket
if(paillier.empty())
{
   return 1;
}
rn.seed(random_device()());
n.run(dist6(rn), {}, true, network);
std::cout << paillier.size() <<std::endl; //Here,the size is 1024
n.bootstrap(argv[5],argv[6],argv[3]);
std::cout << paillier.size() <<std::endl; //Here,the size is 400
```

Why does it happen?
I tried to store paillier in a pointer, reference, const and static. That always happens.

Comment: Unless I'm just missing it, none of the code you've posted actually uses the string after it is initialized. If the size is randomly changing that seems like you may be corrupting the stack. Since your example is not complete it's just a guess since we can't see what your code is actually doing.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I think too. But the content is same. When I put std::cout << paillier, the result is equal.

Comment: @LucasDias: It *should be* the same; you're not modifying the string. So why would its value change? Does `handle_response` return a reference or something?

Comment: I wonder if this could be a result of the old non-compliant `std::string` implementation which used reference counting and copy-on-write.

Comment: In either case, running under a debugger with a watchpoint or two for the `string` private members and/or `char` values might help.

Comment: @NicolBolas handle_response return just std::string

Comment: Thanks @aschepler. I will try.